# HTML Canvas slow in Safari, crashes in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, safari

This is the [page](http://xiaohenry.github.io)

I'm making an intro page to my site, and in

Firefox: unresponsive script / site crashes

Safari: the script is extremely slow and the nodes move really slow

Chrome: works for the most part when you type in the url, but when you access the page through a link, the script sometimes FAILS to load and I get "Cannot read getContext of null".

Thank you for any feedback. I just began web programming and advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A large part of the problem is with `shadowblur`.

Have a look at this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/shadowblur-performance). Performance is very, very poor.

Comment: Hmmm. I commented out all the shadow effects but I'm still getting a pretty severe lag issue in firefox

Comment: I think that's just because you're drawing a lot of lines on a large canvas. Use fewer nodes, or decrease distanceThreshold. And it might help to close your paths.

Also, check this out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I appreciate them. I went ahead and  did exactly just that. Decreasing everything definitely made a huge difference in performance. But is there a huge flaw in how I'm writing my code? Or is this simply a discrepancy in browser capability? Hmm.. after looking at this site:http://jenniferdewalt.com/electro_bounce/page. Looks like it's my code..

Comment: My experience is that firefox does not generally perform as well as chrome, speed-wise. Are you familiar with your browser's developer tools? These will help you profile your code. E.g., profiling your code reveals that `stroke` seems to be what's taking most of the time.

Comment: Also, the way you're checking distances between nodes is O(n^2), which could be improved on. In this case, though, I don't know if any of the alternatives would really be worthwhile.

Comment: I'm really new to web development, so I'm not very familiar. Could you explain developer tools?

Comment: Gotta go to sleep, but: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools and http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ (the second one is probably a little out of date with the newest chrome, but should still be good overall)

Comment: Sounds good. Gonna keep hacking away at it. Appreciate the help